# Preferences to change the background animation of an app

Tags: java, android, list, listpreference

I am trying to make Settings in the app, specificly a ListPreference to be able to change the background animation of the app, but I can't do it, nothing changes if you choose option 1 or option 2... I followed a similar tutorial and tried to make it work for me, but nothing so far.
Here is the java

```
SharedPreferences backChooser = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String values = backChooser.getString("list", "1");
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim1);
    animation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getDrawable();
    animation.start();

    if (values.contentEquals("1")) {
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim1);
        animation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getDrawable();
        animation.start();
    }
    if (values.contentEquals("2")) {
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim2);
        animation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getDrawable();
        animation.start();
    }
```

and here is the xml of the preferences

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/list"
    android:entryValues="@array/listvalues"
    android:key="list"
    android:summary="This is a list to choose from"
    android:title="List" />
```

Comment: are you doing this in `onCreate()` by any chance ?

Comment: yes, why, I want the app to be simple, to just display animation and sound

Comment: see my answer as to the why and how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim1);
```

sets an ImageView's "Background".

Were as this code

```
img.getDrawable();
```

gets an ImageView's "Drawable" or the image on it, not the actual "Background" image.

Since you want to retrieve the image that you've once set as the BG of "img", this code

```
img.getBackground();
```

is the one that you need.

Comment: it is an animation, if I do it with getBackground the animation doesn't run